# Failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> I created a new project using `react-native init Wevaha`,after that I
>   excute it work's properly then I modified sample app based on my
>   requirement again run it works properly but the next time while
>   running the app I am gettingthe error like
>
> ```
> ' Application Wevaha has not been registered.This is either due to a require() error during intialization or failure to call
> ```
>
> AppRegistry.registerComponent'
>
> The screen shot attached below please find it
>   [image]

Comment: Can you show us your `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js` file please ?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly that's wrong for this situation. The error would most likely be in the index.ios.js file or the index.android.js file

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It is likely that you already have another React Native packager server running for another app or that the app name in AppDelegate.m and your index.js is not the same.

Try closing all terminal windows, double check the value of `moduleName` and run the project again.

Comment: not working for me, closed the packager server, and checked the moduleName. argh.

Comment: How to fix this for expo app ?

Answer (score 36):

For us, the problem was that the name of the app registered did not match the root folder. So, if your root folder is `/ChatApp`, then register your app as so:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ChatApp', ()  => App);
```

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on what oblador said, I was still having this issue after closing all the terminal windows/killing all the other React Native processes. What happened to me was the value of the `moduleName` in `AppDelegate.m` (in the root of the XCode project) was incorrect. I am using a build from [Barton Hammond's Snowflake](https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake) and was trying to rename it from "snowflake" to my own and I missed this value and was getting that error.

Comment: If you manually update `moduleName` in `AppDelegate.m` does that solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, manually update it? I set the value to what I wanted and it fixed the problem.

Comment: app name in app.js file match with name inside app delegate but I still have this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it is caused by the case sensitivity of the app name in `index.ios.js`.

It works after I changed from

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppleReactNative', () => App)
```

to

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('applereactnative', () => App)
```

Comment: If running on MacOS with the new React Native for macOS, this needs to be changed in app.json

Answer (score 6):

For my case, I take a look at packager port number in which it's listening.
It's the result from your calling `npm start` at your root project directory.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │
 │  prefer.                                                                   │
 │                                                                            │
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │
 │                                                                            │
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Then I check which application is listening on that port via

`lsof -i :8081`

Result:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
AwesomePr 8131 haxpor    9u  IPv6 0x372bdab8e928e839      0t0  TCP localhost:56484->localhost:sunproxyadmin (SYN_SENT)
```

Now take that `PID` number, and force killing it via

`kill -9 8131`

Run your packager again ideally with resetting of cache via `npm start -- --reset-cache`, it should be fine now.

**FYI**:

react: `15.4.2`, react-native: `0.41.2`

Answer (score 3):

Killing all other node processes worked for me
ie.

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

to find those process and

```
pkill -f node
```

to kill the processes

Answer (score 1):

If facing this issue while running on android device or android emulator,

apart from  index.js You should also make sure that app name should be the same in below file `index.android.bundle`:

which you can find at this path:  `~android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

Search for the old app name and replace it with the actual name.

it worked for me, hope it helps others too.

Comment: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'U.startApp'), stack i have getting this type error help me you have any idea.

i am find 'U.startApp' in index.android.bundle

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that the name of the app registered in `package.json`matches the name of the root folder.
In my react native app it is as follows. Make sure you import name as appName (camelCase) from ./app.json as shown below:

```
import React from 'react'
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './app/index';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise'
import reducers from './app/store/reducers'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(
    reducers,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware))
)
const appRedux = () => {
    return(
        <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
    
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => appRedux);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just run:

`npx react-native-rename <newName> -b <bundleIdentifier>`

and it does not override `ReactNativeFlipper.java`

so I have to rename it from

> android\app\src\debug\java\com\oldprojname\ReactNativeFlipper.java

to

> android\app\src\debug\java\com\newprojname\ReactNativeFlipper.java

```
and changed inside `ReactNativeFlipper.java`

-com.oldproname

+com.newprojname
```

and make sure you change inside app.json

> {
> "name": "newprojname",
> "displayName": "newname"
> }

Answer (score 0):

just remove the small bracket from ((appName, () => App));

```
 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, ()  => App);
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a project name with lowercase alphabets

It worked for me :)

Example :

```
npx react-native init <projectname>
```

Comment: This response does not fit the what was required as the error has nothing to do with the naming

Comment: try deleting node_modules and reinstall using your package manager

or 

All things considered, you as of now have another React Native packager worker running for another application or that the application name in AppDelegate.m and your index.js isn't something similar. 



Have a go at shutting every terminal window, twofold check the worth of moduleName, and run the task once more.

Answer (score 0):

In `android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainActivity.java`, changing:

```java
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
  return "MyApp";
}
```

to:

```java
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
  return "main";
}
```

fixed the problem in my application, which I've faced after upgrading `Expo`/`React Native` to newer version.