# Error Registry AppRegistry Android (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Having a problem shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449248/failure-to-call-appregistry-registercomponent)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, this error happens because you app name provided in the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` is not your app name. You name to use the same name that you choose when doing `react-native init my-app-name`. To find your app name, open you `app.json` file and it should be the value of the name property. Be aware that the name is case sensitive.