# I am receiving an error when connecting to my store! *First attempt at implementing Redux*

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

as I stated in my title, this is my first attempt at redux so bare with me. I tried a few different tutorials and taking what I could and implementing it into my code was interesting to say the least. But when I finally came to the end, using connect() to get to my store, I received the error

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(SignUpEmailPage)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(SignUpEmailPage) in connect options.

I can only assume the error is coming from the bottom of my SignUpEmailPage.

Below, I have uploaded the files used to create redux.

I want to also say I know this is a hefty question! I appreciate any insight way more than you guys know! Redux is pretty complicated for a newbie like so!:)

**types.js -> ADD_LIKED/ADD_DISLIKED are just thoughts in my head for later possible use**

```
export const ADD_EMAIL = 'ADD_EMAIL';
export const ADD_LIKED = 'ADD_LIKED';
export const ADD_DISLIKED = 'ADD_DISLIKED';
```

**appReducer.js** -> irrelevant to the question but I think I need a different reducer for ADD_LIKED/ADD_DISLIKED. Email and those two are not correlated and the states are different. So they should be in different reducers correct? Still confused about those honestly. Ill save this for another question lol

```
import { ADD_EMAIL, ADD_LIKED } from '../actions/types.js';

const initialState = {
    email: null,

    //this is all in theory
    dislilkeList: [],
    likedList: []
}

const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_EMAIL:
            return {...state,
            email: state.email({
             name: action   
            })
        }
        case ADD_LIKED:
            return {...state,
            swipedLeft: state.likedList.concat({//test with push rather than concat
               key: Math.random(),
               name: action     
                })
            }   
        case ADD_DISLIKED:
            return {...state,
            swipedLeft: state.dislikedList.concat({//test with push rather than concat
                key: Math.random(),
                name: action     
                })
            }      
        default:
            return state;


    }
}

export default appReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import appReducer from '../reducers/appReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    email: appReducer
})

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer)

export default configureStore;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './components/store';

const store = configureStore();

const providerComponent = () =>
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => providerComponent);
```

**And Finally,**

I have the two pages where I am creating the state, and sending it to another page. I am trying to take a email input and send it to my password page for display. I know its a simple task for redux, but I plan on using redux for other things in the future.

**SignUpEmail.js** Im only including the code I think you guys need

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SignUpEmailPage extends Component {

state = {
  email: null
}

render()
 <Container style = {styles.emailInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel >
            <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Email Address</Label>
                <Input
                value = {this.state.email}
                onChange={(email) => this.setState({ email })}                
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}               
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
                />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Container>

     <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <ContinueButton
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreatePassword')} 
      /> 
      </View>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    email: state.email.CreatePasswordPage
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (SignUpEmailPage);
```

**CreatePassword.js** -> I havent tried printing the state yet, havent got that far, would be nice to know how though:)

```
import {connect } from 'react-redux';

class CreatePasswordPage extends Component {

render()
<Container style = {styles.passwordInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel>
           <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Password</Label>
              <Input
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}
                
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
         
              />
         </Item>
       </Form>
      </Container>

//deals with connecting to store
//maps states
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    email: state.email.CreatePasswordPage
  }
}
//maps actions, for future purposes
const mapDispatchToProps = (state) => {

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (CreatePasswordPage);
```

Comment: Apart from the problem stated here, just for your info: the style of redux you are using here is a very old style we don't recommend learning any more - you are most likely following a very outdated tutorial. Please follow the official redux tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: Generally, this seems to be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449248/failure-to-call-appregistry-registercomponent/42120151 - please check the solutions given over there. Maybe you are also registering your `appName` twice and it uses the wrong one or someting like that?

Comment: @phry well thats unfortunate, I will try and update myself! Thankyou

Comment: I will look into that other question! Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0):

See if you get an error if you remove the space in this line:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (SignUpEmailPage)
```

To

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignUpEmailPage)
```

Comment: I got excited but unfortunately that did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

check you have document.getElementByID('root')

Comment: I haven't used this style of react its similar but there a few difference like not using usedispatch and useselector

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your store.js file to this

```html
import { createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import appReducer from '../reducers/appReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    email: appReducer
})

const initialState = {}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState)

export default store;
```

and your index.js file to this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './components/store';

const providerComponent = () =>
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => providerComponent);
```